# Xamarin Android live stream video/audio from device in c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera

I am challenged with the task to stream video and audio (camera and mic) from my android API 19 devices directly to a server. Displaying (on the device) is also optional.
Following this [link](https://foxdogstudios.com/peepers) I learned that you can use Mediarecorder with a socket instead of an output file. But they describe this method is to slow (3 seconds delay), because of the encoding. They also show a second method with preview frames (as MJpeg) but only for video.

Some apps from the store use the same method with an additional audio recorder, which causes a big delay between image and sound. I was hoping someone knows how to live stream from android to a server over wifi. C# code would be much appreciated. Third-party libraries are also welcome as long as they are free for commercial use. Any help/ideas are welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: What format does the media server accept?

Comment: You will likely need to drop down to the [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API and have your own code to pull frames from the camera and mux with the microphone.

Comment: SushiHangover I think I would be happy with any format I can get.

Comment: thanks I will look into the MediaCodec

Comment: This question is off topic as it is unfortunately. In any case, if I were you I'd start by just getting frames from your camera. Once you have a stream of data, it shouldn't be hard to set up a socket / TCP connection to a server and send the data over. Also, once you actually have something, this forum will be able to help you better. Lastly, putting *Java code will be reluctantly accepted* on SO (which explicitly frowns upon questions blatently asking for code) is playing with fire.

Comment: @b.holz `any format I can get`... that does not make sense in terms of wanting a real-time stream to a server, what are you going to do with it when it reaches the server?

Comment: @SushiHangover the goal is to display and save it.

Comment: @b.holz Start with the type of media server that you will be running first...